# Call the same function (read: function by same name that has same return type) on several objects of different, unknown classes

Tags: java, swing, polymorphism

Imagine the following, simple Swing program with three `Component`s, a `JLabel`, a `JTextField` and a `JCheckBox`:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;

public class Example {

    private JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Example window = new Example();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Example() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 0));

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("FOO");
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

        JTextField textField = new JTextField("BAZ");
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField);

        JCheckBox chckbxBar = new JCheckBox("BAR");
        frame.getContentPane().add(chckbxBar);
    }

}
```

Now we wish to horizontally align all `Components` to center. Each of these `Component`s' respective classes expose the function `setHorizontalAlignment(int alignment)`, yet these classes have no common superclass that does so.

How would I go about polymorphically calling this function on every component in the `JFrame`, or every component in a `List<Component>`?

To further clarify, here's roughly what I would do if there was a common superclass called `CommonSuperclass` exposing the necessary function:

```
List<Component> someSwingComponents = /*put some components in the list*/;
for (Component c : someSwingComponents) {
    if (c instanceof CommonSuperclass) {
        //component is horizontally alignable...
        ((CommonSuperclass) c).setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    }
}
```

This would work for *some* `Component`s, for instance `JCheckBox`es, `JRadioButton`s and `JToggleButton`s (where the common superclass would be `JToggleButton`, as it **does have** the required function), but not for the `Component`s whose closest common superclass is `java.awt.Component`, as it **does not have** the required function.

Currently, I have the following ugly and long code that I would like to get rid of:

```
if (component instanceof JLabel) {
    ((JLabel)component).setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
} else if (component instanceof AbstractButton) {
    ((AbstractButton)component).setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
} 
/* And so on for every type of Component that has setHorizontalAlignment()... */
```

I thought of using an interface `IHorizontallyAlignable`, but since I cannot (and certainly do not wish to) modify the classes of each of the Swing `Component`s to implement `IHorizontallyAlignable`, I would instead need a way to signify that these classes **already** fulfill the requirements of the `IHorizontallyAlignable` interface, and therefore can be cast to it, despite not technically implementing it with the `implements` keyword.

I am hoping that Reflection will not be required for something as simple as horizontally aligning every (horizontally alignable) `Component` in a window, but if you can see no other way, please post your Reflection-based answer nonetheless.

Comment: One solution would be to just subclass every component you want horizontally allignable as a wrapper and then have the subclass implement your IHorizontallyAlignable element.

Comment: @Hongyu In this case, I believe there is essentially no difference between doing this and modifying the existing Java classes, which I do not want to do. I am writing a Layout Manager, and I want it to remain as compatible with existing Layout Managers as possible - defining new subclasses of existing Components specific to my Layout Manager does not accomplish this.

Comment: If you don't want to do that, then use element.getClass().getDeclaredMethods() to get all the methods of the object, and then invoke the one you want to use.

Comment: @Hongyu That works, although it should be `getMethods()` as some `Component`s do not define this method - they let their superclass define it, and therefore this method is not always returned by `getDeclaredMethods()`, which only returns methods defined by the specific class, not any superclasses of the class.